# How can i limit the number of characters i can put in an element through DTD?

Tags: xml, dtd

for example i have this code

`<order id_order="l9992223"></order>`

and through DTD i want to limit the maximun number of character to 8 and also that it can only start with a letter but i dont know how the dtd code should be like this without the restriction i want to put

```
<!ELEMENT order>
<!ATTLIST order
id_order CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

i dont know where to start with this and i´ve been pulling my hair all afternoon because i´ve got no idea how to use DTD so thanks in advance if you know how to solve it

Comment: You need to use a better schema language for this, such as XSD or RelaxNG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limits you can specify in DTD with an `<!ATTLIST>` entry is very restricted and simple. You can use `CDATA` for "any possible string", special [tokenized types](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-TokenizedType) or an explicit list of possible values with [enumerations](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-EnumeratedType). Unless you want to define all the possible values with

```
<!ATTLIST order
id_order (1|2|3|4|5|6|.....) #REQUIRED>
```

it is not possible to limit the attribute value to 8 characters.